# Baby-Step Giant Step Algorithm in c#. Hash table out of memory

Tags: c#, hashtable

I am trying to use a hash table to solve a discrete algorithm problem.
I am using Shanks baby step giant step algorithm.
My hash table contains about 11,000,000 keys and values.
I keep getting an out of memory exception.
is there any way to 'fix' this? or a different data structure to use?
I am using Visual C# Express 2010 with .NET 4.0 Framework

Comment: What data types are the keys and the values?  It seems a bit odd to me that you are getting out of memory errors with only 11 million items; so I am guessing it's the data itself that is large.  Are the values sequential (perhaps allowing for the use of simple arrays)?

Comment: I assume the values are `BigInteger`s. And by hashtable you mean `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, right?

Comment: I am using an integer as the key and the value is a BigInteger

Comment: @CodeInChaos I believe it is dictionary...sorry i am very new to programming and this is my first time using a hash table. I will post my code later.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is cheating somewhat, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step)  gives a solution

"The algorithm requires O(m) memory. It is possible to use less memory by choosing a smaller m in the first step of the algorithm. Doing so increases the running time, which then is O(n/m). Alternatively one can use Pollard's rho algorithm for logarithms, which has about the same running time as the baby-step giant-step algorithm, but only a small memory requirement."

Answer (score -1):

Try targeting a 64-bit platform.  32-bit executables often run out of virtual memory space these days.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by targeting a 64 bit platform? I am running a 64 bit system. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Good start - what CPU target does your project use?  32-bit? 64-bit? AnyCPU?  If it's 64-bit or AnyCPU you should be in good shape.

Comment: I dont have access to my files atm, so i will try this and get back later tonight. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Keep in mind, however, that CLR imposes a 2Gb limit on any single object. You cannot allocate an array larger than 2Gb in any version of .NET (32/64-bit), for example.

Comment: @Groo: oooh, I learned something new!  I always assumed that you could allocate huge arrays in 64-bit since they added Array.LongLength to .NET 2.0.  Guess I was wrong: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx  (goes to show how often I actually need to allocate large arrays!)