# Hashtable of size 2^24 throws out of memory exception, trying to solve discrete logs with Shanks BSGS

Tags: c#, hashtable

I am trying to solve a discrete log 2^x = r (mod m).
where m, 2^47

So i created a hashtable of size 2^24 and using it to store an integer key and a BigInteger value.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Numerics;

    namespace Shanks_BSGS_Algorithm
    {
        class Program
        {
            static int Main()
            {
                BigInteger g = 2,temp = 2,n = (Math.Sqrt(281474976710656));
                Hashtable b = new Hashtable(n);
                int i=0;
                b.Add(0, 1);
                i++;
                for (i = 1; (BigInteger)i < n ; i++)
                {
                    temp *= g;
                    b.Add(i,temp);
                }

                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also if it makes a difference. I am running this on Visual C# 2010 Express on a 6yr old laptop with 1.5 gb RAM and 32-bit Windows 7.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you get the exception, at new Hashtable or during the loop?

Comment: No, this does not throw an OOM

Comment: HashTable is a bad choice, use `HashSet<BigInt>`

Comment: @ Henk Holtermani'm going to run it again. How long should this code take to run? approximately

Comment: Nook, please do and post exact code. This reeks of untested 'edits' while posting.

Comment: oops my mod is between 2^47 and 2^48. so my n is sqrt of (2^48)

Comment: `Math.Sqrt(2^48)` is total nonsense as well.

Comment: @Nook: try adding this line at the beginning of the `Main` method: `Console.WriteLine(2^24);`.

Comment: Right, we have code that is somewhat credible. Now, what's the actual question? How to squeeze 5GB into a 2GB memory space?

Comment: @ Hank: so by your remark that means that the temp values become too big to store i assume, I would like to know if there is a different way to do this.

Comment: @Nook: would [Pollard's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) be acceptable? It uses much less memory with a similar running time.

Comment: @Groo thanks for your help. i completely messed up and im gonna store temp (mod m). which should fix the problem. But i also need to make another table to store more numbers. how would i search both tables to see if they have a common value

Comment: @Nook: I am not that familiar with the algorithm, so I am not so sure you can use a modulo instead of the actual value?

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of [Baby-Step Giant Step Algorithm in c#. Hash table out of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472130/baby-step-giant-step-algorithm-in-c-hash-table-out-of-memory). It even appears it's the same user (with reasonable doubt, of course).

Answer (score 0):

`temp` becomes very big (up to 16777216 bit). So your hashset contains 16 million very long BigIntegers. Maybe you want to reduce temp mod m, but of course this will eventually become 0 when g = 2 and m is a power of 2. So it's not really clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you need to use the `temp` value as the key to your data:

```
// this makes more sense, otherwise you
// could simply have an array of BigIntegers
b.Add(temp,i);
```

Regarding the memory issue, .NET doesn't allow any process to use more than 2Gb of memory, and allows even less if you need a contiguous block. Since you are dealing with very large numbers as you go along, running out of memory is inevitable.

One solution (preferred, if you only need the end result) would be to use a different algorithm ([Pollard's rho algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms)), which is much more space efficient, and has a similar running time.

If you really want to test the BSGS algorithm, you will probably need to go for a disk-based hashtable. I am not aware of any implementations for .NET, but you might find several C++ projects around and see if you can port them easily ([DBH](http://dbh.sourceforge.net/), for instance).

If you cannot find such a hashtable, a simpler solution than porting (well, depending on your DB skills) might be to use a relational database you are comfortable with, using a schema that can allow sufficiently large integers. You could try with SQLite, it *will* get slower as it grows, but I believe speed is not that important to you. SQL Server with some proper indexing might work well.